# Change background-position with Jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a code:

```
$( ".produtosMenuItensTit" ).click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-position','left 0');
});
```

When I click in `div produtosMenuItensTit` it changes background position.
But, when I click again, I want main position back.

I tried

```
else {$(this).css('background-position','left -25px');
```

But, doesn't work.

Comment: Good good, we have the `else`, but what is the `if `?

Comment: obviously clicking will only apply `left 0` and nothing else the way it is, you need to use a flag bool to know if its changed and if yes then you use the code from `else` block you showed

Comment: Just use `toggleClass` and do it like that.